# How to reduce the size of mp3 file in Android created using MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

My app creates audio files using MediaRecorder class and I need to upload these created files to a server. Therefore I need these files to be of minimum size so that they can be easily uploaded.
Size reduction may include some degradation of quality.

Comment: Record for less time. Or, reduce the audio recording bit rate.

Comment: What @CommonsWare said: there are configurations for both BitRate and SamplingRate right there on `MediaRecorder`. Pick whichever you want.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `.amr` file format in place of `MP3`, because its auto create the reduced size file compare to mp3.

Answer (score 0):

I think these settings will be optimal for low size and low quality:

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(5512);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(32000);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```